# No output in finding all occurrences of a key in a nested python JSON

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have this sample JSON which is complex and has many levels of nesting as well items in in:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Single",
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "urn:uuid",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Employee",
        "id": "4cb1a87c",
        "text": {
          "status": "generated",
          "div": "generated"
        },
        "extension": [],
        "identifier": [
          {
            "system": "https://github.com",
            "value": "43f123441901"
          }
        ],
        "name": [
          {
            "use": "official",
            "family": "Shields52",
            "given": [
              "Aaro97"
            ],
            "prefix": [
              "Mr."
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maritalStatus": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "MaritalStatus",
              "code": "M",
              "display": "M"
            }
          ],
          "text": "M"
        },
        "multipleBirthBoolean": false
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "User"
      }
    },
{
      "fullUrl": "f411764e1f01",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Claim",
        "id": "411764e1f01",
        "status": "active",
        "type": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "type",
              "code": "Company"
            }
          ]
        },
        "use": "claim",
        "employee": {
          "reference": "1141dfb308"
        },
        "billablePeriod": {
          "start": "2009-12-24T16:42:36-05:00",
          "end": "2009-12-24T16:57:36-05:00"
        },
        "created": "2009-12-24T16:57:36-05:00",
        "provider": {
          "reference": "7e31e2b3feb"
        },
        "priority": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "Employee",
              "code": "normal"
            }
          ]
        },
        "procedure": [
          {
            "sequence": 1,
            "procedureReference": {
              "reference": "58f373a0a0e"
            }
          }
        ],
        "insurance": [
          {
            "sequence": 1,
            "focal": true,
            "coverage": {
              "display": "Employer"
            }
          }
        ],
        "item": [
          {
            "sequence": 1,
            "productOrService": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://comp1.info/",
                  "code": "1349003",
                  "display": "check up"
                }
              ],
              "text": "check up"
            },
            "encounter": [
              {
                "reference": "bc0a5705f6"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "sequence": 2,
            "procedureSequence": [
              1
            ],
            "productOrService": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://comp.info",
                  "code": "421000124101",
                  "display": "Documentation"
                }
              ],
              "text": "Documentation"
            },
            "net": {
              "value": 116.60,
              "currency": "USD"
            }
          }
        ],
        "total": {
          "value": 163.7,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Employee"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

I have only kept 2 items under `entry` but in actual there are thousands of items.

What I am trying to do is find, print all occurrences of a key (print and save key and value both of each occurrence) into a separate dict. So, for example if in above case, I want to find all data for key 'productOrService', then print

```
    "productOrService": {
                  "coding": [
                    {
                      "system": "http://comp.info",
                      "code": "421000124101",
                      "display": "Documentation"
                    }
                  ],
                  "text": "Documentation"
            }
```

Similarly I have to search for any other key at any level of nesting - for example search for `insurance`.

Here is the code I have:

```
 def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               print(x)
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                print(x)
```

When I execute about with `findkeys(input_json,'productOrService')`, then I don't see any output coming in. Not sure what mistake I am making

**Edit**: I understand the issue is with use `yield` but I can't figure out how to replace `yield`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `yield` in your function, that means that it is not a function anymore - it's a iterator. If you want to get an output, iterate through it:

`for x in findkeys(node,"productOrService"): print(x)`

Comment: If I have to modify so that it doesn't yield but does print, how would that change be?

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a generator, which is not printed. Try `list(findkeys(input_json,'productOrService'))`, which will print to the console.

If you don't want to use `yield`, you can instead just iterate over the JSON data recursively and print whenever you encounter a match, without iterating over the output of your function`findkeys`. So you can try something like this:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
if isinstance(node, list):
    for x in node:
        findkeys(x, kv)
elif isinstance(node, dict):
    if kv in node:
        print(node[kv])
    for j in node.values():
        findkeys(j, kv)
```

Comment: If I have to modify so that it doesn't yield but does print, how would that change be?

Comment: I modified my answer with a solution without using `yield`